TypeError: StoreFactory.get_store() got an unexpected keyword argument 'notification_address' in GridDB Py Client
I'm trying to get started with GridDB on my Ubuntu system, and I've installed the GridDB Python client (griddb-python). While attempting to connect to my GridDB store, I encountered the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panda/dev/python/create_db.py", line 13, in <module>
    store = factory.get_store(
TypeError: StoreFactory.get_store() got an unexpected keyword argument 'notification_address'

Here is the code that I tried:
    import griddb_python as griddb

    factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

    # Trying to connect to the store
    store = factory.get_store(
        notification_address="239.0.0.1",
        notification_port=31999,
        cluster_name="defaultCluster",
        username="admin",
        password="admin"
    )

    # Creating a container
    conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("SampleContainer",
                                   [["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
                                    ["status", griddb.Type.BOOL]],
                                   griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)
    container = store.put_container(conInfo)


Steps I've Taken:

Installed griddb-python using pip
Installed required dependencies like pandas
Ran the above code to connect to the GridDB store.

The Problem:
The error suggests that the get_store() method doesn't recognize the notification_address keyword argument. I've followed the examples from the official documentation, and I'm not sure why this is happening. Could this be a version issue or something else I might be missing?
Environment:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Python version: 3.10

